# Why preserveOriginal doesn't work as described in java doc?

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have the following configuration:

```
@AnalyzerDef(name = "autocompleteNGramAnalyzer",

        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),

        filters = {

                @TokenFilterDef(factory = WordDelimiterFilterFactory.class,
                        params = @Parameter(name = "preserveOriginal", value = "1"))
```

`preserveOriginal` doc:

> /**    * Causes original words are preserved and added to the subword
>   list (Defaults to false)    *
>
> * "500-42" => "500" "42"
>   "500-42"    */

According this one I have added following word:

> 500-42

I rebuild  index, reopen Luke and see following:

[image]

only `500` and `42` tokens where are no `500-42`

Why?

Comment: Try to change tokenizer to `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`

Comment: @Oleg, thanks this works

Answer (score 2):

Your `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` only works on tokens that are provided to it, which may not be the original text.

In your case, you use a `StandardTokenizer`, so by the time WordDelimiterFilterFactory starts processing the string, it has already been split into two tokens (`500` and `42`).

Comment: Can you help me with configuration. 1.MyFisrtProcedure -> my first procedure myfirstprocedure. 2. superboy1-> superboy 1 superboy1 3.my-favourite-friend -> my favourite friend my-favourite-friend

Comment: Can you help me with configuration.   1.MyFisrtProcedure -> my first procedure myfirstprocedure.   2. superboy123-> superboy 123 superboy123 
  3.my-favourite-friend -> my favourite friend my-favourite-friend